# Проблемы при создании тригера в SQL Server Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

При создании таблиц в SQL, в одной из них мне понадобилось что бы одна ячейка подсчитывала значения из некоторых других ячеек этой же таблици. Я нашел решение использовав тригер, но он почему то работает только при заполнении ячеек строки которых уже были частично заполнены или если исправляю уже заполненые строки.

Вот созданый мной тригер:

```sql
USE [C_sharp]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[UpdateFull_VitratTrigger1]    Script Date: 25.12.2023 14:46:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateFull_VitratTrigger1]
ON [dbo].[Operetion]  -- Замініть dbo.Operetion на схему та ім'я вашої таблиці
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE o
    SET Full_vitrat = ISNULL(i.Game, 0) + ISNULL(i.Cafe, 0) + ISNULL(i.Prodact, 0) + ISNULL(i.Flowers, 0) + ISNULL(i.Books, 0) + ISNULL(i.Passgase, 0) + ISNULL(i.Utilities, 0) + ISNULL(i.Oters, 0)
    FROM Operetion o
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON o.ID_vit = i.ID_vit;
END;
```

`Full_vitrat` - это ячейка которая подсчитывает значения остальных ячеек.

При заполении новой (совсем пустой строки) мне выдает следующую ошибку (описание которой прикреплю ниже):

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Строки не были обновлены.
Данные в строке 4 не были зафиксированы.
Источник ошибки: Framework Microsoft SqIClient Data
Provider.
Сообщение об ошибке: Cannot insert the value NULL into
column 'Opis', table 'C_sharp.dbo.Operetion'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Исправьте ошибки и повторите попытку или нажмите клавишу ESC, чтобы отменить изменения.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ну вот же всё написано: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Opis', table 'C_sharp.dbo.Operetion'; column does not allow nulls." Колонка `Opis` не захотела принимать пустое значение, укажите ей какое-то значение для записи. Ну либо объявите эту колонку `nullable`, если не хотите в неё ничего писать. И вообще дело похоже не в триггере. У вас сама вставка не сработала. "INSERT fails"

Comment: Нет в таблице ячеек. Есть записи, есть поля, есть значение определённого поля определённой записи. *что бы одна ячейка подсчитывала значения из некоторых других ячеек этой же таблици* Значение указанного поля в этой записи считается на основании значений других полей той же записи? Тогда нафига триггер? есть же вычисляемые поля.